# Improving performance by making own Coordinate class instead of using Point2D

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking

I just were thinking about if it would give you performance if you make your own class e.g.

```
public class Coordinate{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /* Getters & Setter */

    /* etc. */
}
```

Would that be more performance than if you would use `Point2D` or would that be somewhat equal in performance?

I know it is a naive question but I found nothing when searching the Internet.

Comment: Even if there is a performance gain it is very very subtle in todays computing.

Comment: Take benchmarks for with custom class/with Point2D and see if there is any difference.

Comment: What happened when you wrote a little test program that told you the performance of each? How are you using each?

Comment: Well using ``System.nanotime()`` and making 2.147.483.647 instances of each class it seems that ``Point2D`` does need double the time of ``Coordinate``.

Comment: The golden rule of optimisation is to do absolutely nothing until you've proven that this piece of code is the bottleneck in your application and your overall performance is not good enough. Have you determined that? If not, I'd not worry and move on..

Comment: Point2D uses float and double as co-ordinate types, and since you are using ints, there sure should be some performance gain, as integer arithmetic is faster compared to floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not need to create your own `Coordinate` class, because there already exists a class `java.awt.Point` with fields `int x;` and `int y;`. This class also implements `java.awt.geom.Point2D` so it is easy to use with existing code that expects a `Point2D`.

Whether this improves performance: since you haven't told us what you intend to use it for, there's no way to tell. If you're going to use Java2D features such as transforms, constructing `Shape`s or `Path2D`s then it's not likely to improve performance and may even reduce it due to frequent conversion between `int` and `double`.

If you're only going to use it with your own code and only intend to perform integer arithmetic, and that in tight loops with many iterations, then you're likely to see some performance improvements as you're now doing integer arithmetic which is faster than floating-point arithmetic on any CPU that I've ever heard of. There's nothing that dynamic HotSpot compilation can change about that difference so it's a pretty sure bet that you're going to see at least some improvement.

But if you're mixing operations on your Coordinate/Point with other calculations, or I/O, then these other operations will not change in performance characteristics so the performance gains from the integer arithmetic will be a smaller percentage of your overall performance.

Comment: I use OpenGL for creating a simple game and I won't use Java2D anywhere, but that answers my question and +1 for giving a detailed answer.